# Getting Skype Status after the call ends

Tags: .net, vb.net, skype4com

I wrote the following code inside a function which returns status. It was working fine, but now it sets the status as soon as the Skype call is made. So, the status is set as "Routing" for every call instead of "refused", "cancelled", "finished" etc. I want to get the final status of the call.
Furthermore, how do I make the rest of the code until the call is finished. I would also like to get the duration of call, but right now it sets it to zero, because the next lines of code get executed as soon as the call is placed.
I am using **Skype4COM Lib**.
Here's the code:

```
 Private Function placeSkypeCall(ByVal number As String, ByRef status As String)

    Dim oSkype = skype
    If Not oSkype.Client.IsRunning Then
        oSkype.Client.Start()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000)
    End If

    ''Setting Necessary Constant Variables to interact with Skype object
    Dim cUserStatus_Offline = oSkype.Convert.TextToUserStatus("OFFLINE")
    Dim cUserStatus_Online = oSkype.Convert.TextToUserStatus("ONLINE")

    'Setting the user as online
    If cUserStatus_Offline = oSkype.CurrentUserStatus Then
        oSkype.ChangeUserStatus(cUserStatus_Online)
    End If

    'Setting an end user
    Dim oUser = oSkype.User(number)

    'placing the call
    Dim oCall = oSkype.PlaceCall(oUser.Handle)

    status = oSkype.Convert.CallStatusToText(oCall.Status)
    If status.ToString() = "Finished" Then
        status = "Success"
    ElseIf status.ToString() = "Refused" Then
        status = "Declined"
    ElseIf status.ToString() = "Cancelled" Then
        status = "Unanswered"
    End If

    Return status
End Function
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken there are a few events related to calls in Skype4COM. Have you looked through all the available events of the `skype` object? By the way in case you didn't know the Skype4COM API was deprecated a few years back, meaning a lot of its functionality have been (or will be) lost.

Comment: @VisualVincent Yes, I know that it has been deprecated, but this event was working fine a few days ago. It just started having issues only 3 days ago. Plus, I have looked through all the events of the object, but I didn't find anything useful.

Comment: AFAIK the `PlaceCall()` method doesn't block. However the `Skype` class has got an event called `CallStatus` which is raised every time a call's status changes. Thus you cannot get it from a function, but you have to react to it in the event.

Comment: @VisualVincent I am using that method in the code above, but what I can't figure out is how to use it properly. Currently, it sets the status as soon as I place call. I want it to set status once the call has ended, and the code moves onto the next line as soon as the call is placed. It doesn't wait for the call to end. How do I use status method after call ends.

Comment: I literally just told it that: The `PlaceCall()` method doesn't block, so you need to use the `Skype.CallStatus` event to react to status changes. You cannot use a function for this.